# How to count the sum of sum?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that returns this its sum of a table and name:

```
sum                  name
2                    business1
3                    business2
4                    business3
1                    business4
```

I want like below:

```
sum              name        precentage
2                business1     0,2
3                business2     0,3
4                business3     0,4
1                business4     0,1
```

I tried below Query:

```
SELECT  
  SUM(table1.value) AS sum,
  COUNT(SUM(table1.value)/SUM(sum) as percentage,
  table2.name
  .....
  ....
  ... 
  GROUP BY table2.name
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, I would recommend a subquery in the `FROM` clause:

```
select . . .,
       sum(table1.value) / tsum.sum_value
from . . . cross join
     (select SUM(table1.value) as sum_value from table1) tsum
```